# Netsuite get "Currency Revaluation (Unrealized Gain/Loss)" Table

Tags: netsuite

I am new to netsuite,

Is it possible to get the table "Currency Revaluation (Unrealized Gain/Loss)" using suitescript QL.

[image]
[image]
I would like to use it in Suite QL

here is an sample:

```
SELECT
NT .*
FROM
  NextTransactionLineLink AS NTLL
  INNER JOIN Transaction AS NT ON (NT.ID = NTLL.NextDoc)
  INNER JOIN Transaction ON (Transaction.ID = NTLL.PreviousDoc)
  inner join transactionline tl ON (tl.TRANSACTION = Transaction.id)
  inner join subsidiary sb ON sb.id = tl.subsidiary
  inner join accountingperiod ap ON (
    (ap.id = Transaction.postingperiod)
    AND ap.isposting = 'T'
  )
  inner join accountingperiod pap ON (
    (pap.id = NT.postingperiod)
    AND pap.isposting = 'T'
  )
  inner join currencyrate cr1 ON (
    cr1.basecurrency = sb.currency
    AND cr1.transactioncurrency = Transaction.currency
    AND (
      cr1.effectivedate = To_date(
        ap.startdate,
        'MM/DD/YYYY'
      )
    )
  )
  inner join consolidatedexchangerate cexr ON (
    cexr.postingperiod = Transaction.postingperiod
    AND cexr.fromsubsidiary = tl.subsidiary
    AND cexr.tosubsidiary = 1
  )
WHERE
 (NTLL.NextDoc = 212328)
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

By "getting", I am assuming you want to load this record and the fetch/update the values within.

Simply use `&xml=t` in the url, *after the URL of the record*

Something like this -

```
https://342xxxx-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/vendbill.nl?id=00000&whence=&xml=t
```

You will get the record type.

```
<record recordType="vendorbill"
```

Use this record type in your Script.

```
var objRecord = record.load({
 type: record.Type.VENDOR_BILL, 
 id: 157,
 isDynamic: true,
});
```

If in case the record is a Custom Record, use this

```
 var newFeatureRecord = record.load({
 type: 'customrecord_feature',
 id: 1,
 isDynamic: true 
 });
```

Let me know in case of issues in the comments below.

Comment: It shows the Recordtype as FxReval, but there is no table for fxreval

Comment: Try it like this

var newFeatureRecord = record.load({
 type: 'FxReval',
 id: your_record_id,
 isDynamic: true 
 });

Comment: Is it possible to get those through the query